# FFMPEG audio filter/settings to crossfade but with only the first file becoming quiet

Tags: ffmpeg

I have two audio files that I want to concatenate, while crossfading between them at 3 seconds offset. But I do not want a traditional crossfade with the first file getting quiet while simultaniously the second file gets louder, which I know could be achieved with the `acrossfade` filter, but rather I want only the first file getting quieter, while the second file should start at 100% loudness right away.

I have an idea for a step-by-step procedure where I would

1. strip away the last 3 seconds of the first file into a temporary file
2. strip away the first 3 seconds of the second file into a temporary file
3. apply a `afade=out` filter to the first temporary file
4. merge the two temporary files together
5. concatenate the first file, the merged file, and the second file

all using seperate ffmpeg commands

I guess this would do the trick, but it would be very error-prone I guess, and I was wondering if there was a way to do all I want to achieve with just one command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i audio1 -i audio2 -filter_complex acrossfade=d=3:c2=nofade audio-out
```

FFmpeg version should be from 2019-01-25 or later. Release should be >= 4.2